# AppCache Fatal Error

Tags: internet-explorer, manifest, mime-types, html5-appcache, application-cache

Appcache is working in Chrome perfectly, however in IE(11) I'm getting a very vague "AppCache Fatal Error".

My syntax is as follows:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# 2014 03 04 Verson 1.0.4 #
###########################

/resource.php

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
```

_

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest='<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>/appcache/text/cache-manifest/manifest.appcache' type='text/cache-manifest'>
```

EDIT: I don't think it has anything to do with the size. I emptied all the resources out of the manifest so that is was just the Sections & Version & I still recieved the error.

EDIT 2: I tried it in Safari & receive the following in the console log:

```
Application Cache manifest had an incorrect MIME type: text/plain.
```

So, I guess my MIME type is wrong; how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuring the MIME type will depend on what server you're using. (Note that the `type='text/cache-manifest'` you have on the `<html>` tag doesn't do anything.) If you're using Apache, you should be able to add

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

to either the `.htaccess` file or to your server configuration (`httpd.conf`, `apache.conf`, or something else). See [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#page-header). Similar configuration documentation should be available if you're using a different web server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what squid314 wrote I have noticed when you use cookies the appCache will break in IE 10/11 and FF. But it works for Chrome.

Example:

```
<?php
// usually creates PHPSESSION cookie which will break the appCache for IE and FF
session_start() 
?>
```